# data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" why doesn't this work on Bootstrap-5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Normally, I expect to see the 3 links when I click on the hamburger menu on the right. But when I click on it, it doesn't show me the 3 links that are  Contact, Pricing, and Download. I exactly did the same with the Bootstrap-5 document on the internet.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


<h1>Hello World</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Company</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navbar collapse requires JavaScript. Just add this to your project:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

By the way your code is wrong. You need to add `.container-fluid` or other container inside navbar. Check docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: thank you for answering. Well I am having a course on udemy. The instructor did the same, without adding javascript code, and that container-fluid class, but it worked. I did all the same except she was using bootstrap 4, but im using 5 , so she used data-target, but i used data-bs-target.

Comment: i am watching another video of the instructor, you are right, she just said it worked cause she was using  codeply where the javascript already included. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Well! I don't know it will be helpful for you all or not but It helped me, by doing just this. Remove **data-bs-toggle to data-toggle** and leave everything the same in the dropdown menu button item. I hope it will be helpful to you if it did, then vote up for me. and in the body add this also

```
href=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
              integrity=
"sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" 
              crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src=
"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
                integrity=
"sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
                integrity=
"sha384-oesi62hOLfzrys4LxRF63OJCXdXDipiYWBnvTl9Y9/TRlw5xlKIEHpNyvvDShgf/" 
                crossorigin="anonymous">
```